# Reordering an array in flash as3

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, shared-objects

I have an array of objects, each of which is assigned an ID when it is first created. I give the user the ability to visually reorder the objects, which changes their position in the array. They then have the option to save that order using a flash sharedObject or "cookie" and then later, if they reopen the flash file, I want them to be able to hit a button to restore that order. I'm just not sure what the syntax would be to set the object's index within the array. Here's my code:

VARIABLES:

```
var project_settings = SharedObject.getLocal("settings"); //saves all project settings for the next time the file is opened
var project_order:Array = []; //saves project order for the next time the file is opened
var project_display:Array = []; //saves whether each project should be displayed or hidden for the next time the file is opened
```

SAVE CODE:

```
function saveOrder(){
    for (var i=0;i<project_array.length;i++){
        project_order[i] = project_array[i].id;
        project_display[i] = project_array[i].projectThumb.thumbActive;
    }
    project_settings.data.order = project_order;
    project_settings.data.active = project_display;
    //trace (project_settings.data.active[1]);
    project_settings.flush(); //saves most recent "cookie"
}
```

RESTORE CODE:

```
function loadOrder(){
     for (var i=0;i<project_array.length;i++){
/* NEED THE CODE THAT GOES HERE. BASICALLY, PROJECT_ARRAY[i] SHOULD BE THE ITEM WITH AN ID EQUAL TO PROJECT_SETTINGS.DATA.ORDER[i] */
     }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function loadOrder()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary();

    for (var i = 0; i < project_array.length; i++)
        dict[project_array[i].id] = project_array[i];

    project_array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < project_settings.data.order.length; i++)
        project_array[i] = dict[project_settings.data.order[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just load in your array and sort on the ID. Something like this should work:

```
private function _loadArray():void
{
    // fill in your array
    project_array.sort( this._sortFunc );
}

// replace the * by whatever your object type is
private function _sortFunc( a:*, b:* ):int
{
    return a.id - b.id;
}
```

More info: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort()

Or even the `sortOn()` function (which might be easier) should work:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn()

Comment: That won't work. `project_array` contains the objects that need sorting. `project_settings.data.order` contains the IDs of the objects in the desired order. Your solution completely ignores that second array.

Comment: I think you only really need one array here to be honest. The project_array contains the position ID plus the info that you want sorted. After the user rearranges them, I'd sort that array based on the ID, and save it in the SharedObject in order, so that it's always in the right order. Other than that, the solution proposed by Gerhard should work.

Comment: you're probably right sausageboy - two arrays are not needed however -->